# vb login session

Tags: vb.net, session

Hi I'm completely lost on this piece of code (also very new) I am trying to create a session after the else statement. How do you create a session and for it to be read by another file ?

```
   Dim conn As MySqlConnection
    'connect to DB
    conn = New MySqlConnection()
    conn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;Port=3306; user id=****; password=****; database=testtable"
    'see if connection failed.
    Try
        conn.Open()
    Catch myerror As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show("Error Connection to Database: " & myerror.Message)
    End Try
    'sql query
    Dim myAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter

    Dim sqlquery = "SELECT * FROM members Where login='" & UsernameTextBox.Text & "' and passwd='" & PasswordTextBox.Text & "'"
    Dim myCommand As New MySqlCommand()
    myCommand.Connection = conn
    myCommand.CommandText = sqlquery
    'start query
    myAdapter.SelectCommand = myCommand
    Dim myData As MySqlDataReader
    myData = myCommand.ExecuteReader()
    'see if user exits.
    If myData.HasRows = 0 Then



        MessageBox.Show("Invalid Username/Password", "Login Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    Else


      Dim login As String = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session("login")
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session("login") = UsernameTextBox.Text



        Dim Form1 = New Form1
        Form1.Show()
        Me.Visible = False
    End If
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: Metro? WinForms? WPF? Silverlight? ASP.Net? MonoTouch?

Comment: I know I have vulnerability's but this is just for me to learn

Comment: I'm using window form gui thing on window basic 2008 and adding in the code from there so WinForms

Comment: Session only exists in ASP.Net.

Comment: Is there anyway of passing a text box value to a second form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Session only exists in ASP.Net.

You should pass information in constructor parameters and/or properties of your form classes.